# How do I prevent iPhone from alerting twice when a text message arrives?

Tags: audio, ios, iphone, notifications

How do I prevent the iPhone 5 from beeping twice when a text message arrives?

It beeps twice when there is a new message. I only want one notification. How do I have only one notification instead of two? It plays the notification sound, waits about 2 minutes, then plays it again if the phone is not touched. How do I turn double notification sounds off?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Settings App -> Notifications -> Messages -> Repeat Alerts

change that to "never."  :-)

Let me know if that helped...

Comment: Wow, I thought it was a super annoying bug. But it's actually a feature. Who would have thought there're people who want to be notified multiple times about receiving a text. Pfff.

Comment: LOL, there's an option for "repeat 10 times," too.  I agree this feature is SUPER ANNOYING, and thank you guys for showing me how to stop it.  In fairness to Apple, though, I can see how some people who are *obsessed* with answering messages *immediately* would find it helpful in case they missed the first alert.  Personally I would've made "never" the default, though.